# Rackspace Cloud: Trigger "Rebuild Application" programmatically

Tags: asp.net, automation, rackspace-cloud

I am looking for a way to trigger the "Rebuild Application" functionality on a Cloud Site. I want to add this to a step in my build/release script.

### Here are the avenues I have gone down already:

#### Rename Web.Config

This was a good start, but the system polls for a renamed Web.Config only every 15 mins, so releases could not be "on-demand". This would be a good solution for "nightly" or other automated build schedules.

#### Delete and re-create the Web.Config

Deleting seems to trigger the effect immediately (I don't understand why this differs from renaming, but whatever). The drawback here is that the deploys would not be "seamless" for the duration of the rebuild. I prefer a solution that does not require a "down for maintenance" message, no matter how briefly.

#### API

API is for Cloud Servers only, no Cloud Sites. Darn!

### My Ideas:

#### Watir Script

This is actually an idea I have not pursued yet. I am afraid such a script will be rendered useless or dangerous by the next UI change the Rackspace people make on their admin tool.

#### That is all of my ideas.

Does anyone else have any good ones? Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting, last I checked Cloud Sites didn't even have an API. Only Servers and Files did.

Comment: You're right! Made a note of it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that renaming Web.Config will work just fine.
The polling interval does not appear to be an issue anymore - the rebuilds appear to trigger very quickly.